# Sync vote button with backend vote function

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a vote button which should change color and count immediately in my view. The backend function triggered through the button should process in the backend so the user does not recognize it. The problem is if I change the color of my button in my view with jquery this runs out of sync with the backend function if a user presses the button very fast. So I wanna know how to handle this? If I do it with the ajax response it takes to long.. and this is not a good user experience. I hope you guys understand what I mean?

```
<a data-id="{{ $article->id }}" class="vote {{ Auth::check() && Auth::user()->votedFor($article) ? 'active' : '' }}"></a>

 <div class="points">{{ $article->votes->count() }}</div>
```

The script I wanna use to change color of button and count in my view

```
      $(document).on('click', '.vote', function() {
    var $counter = $(this).parent().find('.points');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $counter.html(parseInt($counter.text(), 10) + 1);
    } else {
      $counter.html(parseInt($counter.text(), 10) - 1);
    }
    var $button = $(this);
    $button.addClass('vote-live');
    var id = $button.data('id');
    var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: "{!! URL::to('article/vote/') !!}/" + id,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {
            "_method": 'POST',
            "_token": token,
            "id": id,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $counter.html(data.count);
            $button.removeClass('vote-live');
            // var color = data.voted ? 'transparent transparent #a53031 transparent' : 'transparent transparent #a53031 transparent';
            // $button.css('border-color', color);
            console.log('success');
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            $button.removeClass('vote-live');
            if (xhr.status == 401) {
                window.location.href = "{!! URL::to('login') !!}";
            } else if (xhr.status == 403) {
                window.location.href = "{!! URL::to('email/verify') !!}";
            }
        },
    });
});
```

Did it like so but dont know if thats the way to go? Looks a little bit unprofessional but I have no idea how its normally done...

```
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
      if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $counter.html(1);
      } else {
        $counter.html(0);
      }
```

Comment: Dude, use a framework.

Comment: You can recommend one?

Comment: I don't know your entire structure, what your web-app is going to do, but to me the evergreen choice is always React. Choosing react would mean understand separation of concerns which in development is important and basically helps you to don't lose your mind.

Comment: I have no idea how to solve my problem with react, never used it. I am using laravel 5.7 which provides vue.js out of the box, but the same never used it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is disabling the button when the service is not completed yet. To do it, you just add class name `.is-sending` when user click the button, this is CSS:

```
.is-sending {
  pointer-events: none; // prevents the pointer event, so they cannot click
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0.6; 
}
```

Then in `success` you remove that class name.
I highly recommend you should use the `button` element instead of `a` element, and in this case you can use `disabled` attribute instead of `.is-sending` class name.

Comment: Thanks a very good idea added the new script above that really works perfectly but sometimes jquery counts wrong. What I mean is instead of 2, 3 is displayed if I click very fast...