# Vote button with Vue and Axios

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, axios

I have an vote button in my app to vote for articles or comments. I almost got that to work with ajax but the sync of clicks and counter is the big problem. I now try to do it with vue js because someone recommended to do so referring to [Sync vote button with backend vote function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52580099/sync-vote-button-with-backend-vote-function).

I have to say I am new to vue js and hope that someone can help me to get this to work. A little specification how I want it to work. A user can toggle the vote button so it adds +1 or 0 and changes the color like here on stack but only with an up button.

What I have for now sends the request to the backend and stores the vote in the database but I dont know how to set up the counter and color properly. What I have so far.

```
<template>
  <div>
      <a class="vote" :class="{ active: hasVotes }" @click="vote"></a>
      <div class="points">{{ votes }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                votes: this.voted
            }
        },

        props: {
            voted: {
                required: true,
                type: Number
            },
            article: {
                required: true,
                type: Object
            }
        },

        computed: {
            hasVotes() {
                return this.votes > 0;
            }
        },

        methods:{
            vote(){
                axios.post('/article/vote/' + this.article.id)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response.data);
                        this.votes = response.count;
                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

What I have else to say is that it is an laravel 5.7 app with vue.js integrated. Maybe it is better to do it with components...?

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to encapsulate this in a component because Vue is data driven and now you actually have to dive into the DOM and manipulate the arrow color for a specific arrow when your count is larger than 0.

I have changed and simplified your code example. The first thing you want to do is not have separate `votes` and `voteCount` properties because they are simply the same thing. You want to receive the initial votes from the backend via an article prop and update it via your XHR call.

I have mocked up a quick example which I have not tested but this should get you going in the proper direction.

Example:

```
<upvote-arrow :article="{{ $article }}"></upvote-arrow>
```

Component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <a class="arrow" :class="{ active: hasVotes }" @click="vote"></a>
        <div class="points">{{ votes }}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                votes: this.article.votes
            }
        },

        props: {
            article: {
                required: true,
                type: Object
            }
        },

        computed: {
            hasVotes() {
                return this.votes > 0;
            }
        },

        methods:{
            vote(){
                axios.post('/article/vote/' + this.article.id)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        this.votes = response.count;
                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    .active {
        border-color: transparent transparent #1267dc transparent;
    }
</style>
```

An `active` class will get applied to the anchor with a computed property when you have more than 1 vote. With this style binding you can change the color of the arrow.

It is also a better idea to only change the votes when the XHR call is actually successful because it might fail for some reason and the proper state is not reflected in that case. Just update the vote with the response of the backend.

Comment: First thank you for your answer and your explanation but I think you missunderstood something. The vote button should have a toggle function so if a user votes for an article it should change the color and add +1. If an user votes again the color should change back and the counter for the user should be at 0. I took your code and registered it properly but the html does not show up although there is no error in the consol. Changed the original post

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand the usage of stackoverflow. We are not here to do your work. If you want a toggle you can easily adjust the sample I have given you. That being said, you need to bind your `article` prop and put the colon in front of it otherwise it will not properly interpret your object.

Comment: Sorry I dont want you to make my work. I only want you to best understand my question. Sorry was not intended! Updated my question. I did not understand how to get the votes of my articles so passed it to my vue js. The problem now is it says **Cannot set property 'votes' of undefined**? Why is it undefined?

Comment: I don't know, and I am afraid this is not really the place to discuss every little error you encounter during your development. I am sure you can figure it out at because it is a pretty basic error message. You can always download the Vue devtools extension for Chrome if you need some extra guidance. Good luck :)

Comment: You are not understanding the scope of the this pointer, unlike programming language JavaScript is a scripting language, so this is not always the object you are writing the code on, but instead it's the object that's calling the code... so at the time of the Click , it's the button object, then the lookup code searches and goes the object stack up to the window object and cant' find the votes property... I'm trying to get my head around this, so I'm sorry i cant' explain it better, research "Scope and Closure in JS" and "Bind and Call" on methods in JS